# Basic getchar()-related function in K&R C book not working?

Tags: c, eof, stdio

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    double nc;

    for(nc=0; getchar()!=EOF; ++nc);
    printf("%1d\n",nc);
}
```

This is my first time learning C, and there are a few things I don't seem to understand too well. The for loop has a rather simple structure the only constraint being if `getchar` does not equal `EOF` (whatever that value `EOF` is set to be). Every time `getchar` does NOT equal `EOF`, `nc` gets incremented. Finally we get out of the for loop with `nc` being adjusted to the length of the string.

However the program is only taking inputs and not displaying the value that should be associated with the length of the character.
What am I not understanding? I'm assuming the book has a much higher chance in being right than me so I guess I'm going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Use `%.0f` instead of `%1d` for `double`. or change type of `nc`.

Comment: The K&R book is great but old, it's not up to datw with modern C. `main()` is no longer valid C, please use `int main()` always. Now to your question. When exactly do you think `getchar()` will be equal `EOF`? Do you think you need to do something special for it? If you don't know, chances are you won't ever be able to hit EOF.

Comment: @WeatherVane, okay, now I see. I thought they wanted to output `nc` on each iteration.

Comment: @n.m. `int main(void)` ;)

Comment: In addition, why are you using `double for counting? Do you count `1.0 sheep, 2.0 sheep, 3.0 sheep...`? It is incorrect to print a `double` with `%1d`, your program will most likely show incorrect results. Use `int` instead.

Comment: @KeineLust It is debatable. The standard says "`int main(void)` or equivalent" without actually defining what's considered equivalent. Most people believe that `int main()` is equivalent to `int main(void)`. It is accepted by every single C compiler in existence anyway. The standard itself has examples of `int main()`.

Comment: @n.m using int makes more sense to count.The only reason I used double was/is the book was using it and I thought it's some c convention.

Comment: @n.m 1)what resources do you suggest for learning c? 2)From what I understand the job of getchar() is to get the character, how was that not aligned with my goal ?

Comment: K&R is actually a great book, keep using it, just bear in mind that `main()` without `int` is outdated.

Comment: Consider changing variable type. Answer to question: you need to type whatever input, press enter so that the input is stored in 'getchar()', and then signal that this is the end of you input, so ctrl + z and enter in the command line; this will count the amount of characters in your input, so what you typed the first time and pressed enter, before typing crtl + z and pressing enter. I also want to add that the question is legit in my opinion because this is not specified in the book and it looks like it is implied that the reader has this as background, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 3):

The program keeps reading input until it comes to the end of the input. If you're typing on a terminal, you need to find out how to signal the end of the input. On Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. On Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS, etc.), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line. Alternatively, make the program read from a file: on a Windows command line, run `myprogram.exe <somefile.txt`. On a Unix-like command line, run `./myprogram <somefile.txt`.

Once the program does reach the end of the file, it'll likely crash or print a nonsensical value, because there's an error in your `printf` statement. `nc` is a floating-point value, but `%d` requires an integer value (more precisely, a value of type `int`). Here are three combinations that work:

- Integer:

  ```
  int nc;
  …
  printf("%d\n", nc);
  ```
- Larger-size integer, like in the first example in K&R — note that it's a lowercase `l`, not a digit `1`:

  ```
  long nc;
  …
  printf("%ld\n", nc);
  ```
- Floating-point number, which may allow larger values (on a modern PC, it allows larger values than `long` in a 32-bit program, but `long` allows larger values in a 64-bit program):

  ```
  double nc;
  …
  printf("%f\n", nc);
  ```

A good compiler would warn you about the mismatch with `printf`. Make sure that you've enabled warnings. For example, here's what `gcc -Wall -O aliman.c` has to say about your program:

```
aliman.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main()
 ^
aliman.c: In function ‘main’:
aliman.c:9:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%1d\n",nc);
     ^
aliman.c:13:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

The warning about the return type of `main` is because `main()` is an obsolete shortcut, in modern C you need to write `int main()`. (Make that `int main(void)` if you're pedantic.) The last warning says that there's no `return` statement — the `main` function must return a value (conventionally, it indicates whether the program succeeded or failed). Both topics will be covered in §1.7.

Comment: `main` need not return a value - the only C function which has the default `return 0;`

Comment: Not `good` compliler but some compilers have ......f functions as a special case and analyse the format string. This has as many enthusiasts as enemies :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Not in C89, which is what you get with many compilers (including the default C dialect when you invoke `gcc`, Borland C which is still popular with learners, and I'm don't know whether Visual Studio has finally made the switch).

Comment: @AliMan This is answer that you were looking for, you need to type whatever input, press enter so that the input is stored in getchar(), and then signal that this is the end of you input, so ctrl + z and enter in the command line; this will count the amount of characters in your input, so what you typed the first time and pressed enter, before typing crtl + z and pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

You have three possible options

1. Change `double` to `int`
2. Change `"%d"` in the `printf()` to `"%lf"`
3. Cast `nc` to `int` like this `(int)nc;`

It will count `'\n'` as well

or if you do not to count '\n'

```
  for (int i = 0; i != EOF; !i ? nc = 0 : nc, i != '\n' && i ?  nc++ : nc, i = getchar());
```

Answer (score 0):

> However the program is only taking inputs and not displaying the value
>   that should be associated with the length of the character. What am I
>   not understanding? I'm assuming the book has a much higher chance in
>   being right than me so I guess I'm going wrong somewhere.

The for loop ends only when the standard input signals EOF. This can be done with `Ctrl+d` on Linux in general. For other operating systems you'd need to find the pendant.

After the for loop ends, the number of characters read will be displayed on standard output.

Some remarks: `nc` should be an integer. The format string for the `printf` function suffices to be `%d` then.

Formatting the source code can help you understand easier. Note that the for loop does not contain the `printf` (as you might have been assuming).

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int nc;
    for(nc=0; getchar()!=EOF; ++nc)
         ;
    printf("%d\n",nc);
}
```